# Can't access website's root page

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

Usually, going to my website, `qpcftw.cu.cc` would load the page `qpcftw.cu.cc/index.php` transparently, without the `/index.php` part showing in the url. I've been trying to get rid of the `.php` extensions using .htaccess. This is the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<Files />
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteRule ^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+)?$              $1.php     [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-z,0-9,_,-]+)/index\.html$    $1.php     [QSA]

ErrorDocument 403 php/error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 405 php/error.php
ErrorDocument 408 php/error.php
ErrorDocument 500 php/error.php
ErrorDocument 502 php/error.php
ErrorDocument 504 php/error.php
```

I need to meet 3 criteria:

1. `qpcftw.cu.cc/index.php` == `qpcftw.cu.cc/index`
2. Visiting `qpcftw.cu.cc/forum/` still loads my PHPBB forum at `qpcftw.cu.cc/forum/index.php`
3. `qpcftw.cu.cc` loads the `index.php` file transparently, without it shown in the URL

So far my current .htaccess fulfills the first 2 needs, but breaks the 3rd. Help! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following .htaccess code automatically does all the extension hiding magic:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blindly adding .php to everything, check if the .php file exists first

```
RewriteCond $1.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9_-]+)?$              $1.php     [L,QSA]

RewriteCond $1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-z0-9_-]+)/index\.html$    $1.php     [L,QSA]
```

This still works for 1 and 2, and 3 now also works because the code will test if index.php.php exists (the request is for index.php), which it doesn't (I hope!), so the RewriteRule will fail.

I've also removed the commas from the regex classes (you can't use those to indicate several groups, putting it in there just means commas are allowed in URLs), and added the [L]ast flag to the rules for better performance

Comment: Great, condition 3 is now met, but unfortunately #2 broke. Perhaps it's a mistake in my links. Should my links point to `/file.php` or just `/file`?

Comment: Right. The first rule should not work for URLs that start with /forum. Add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum` to the first RewriteRule (after `RewriteCond $1.php -f`, on a new line)

Comment: it appears that `/forum/` and `/forum` work the same way anyway

Comment: Oops, i meant it broke #1, not 2